# Regular expression to validate the given input which accepts one space or Hyphen which is part of the text length it has minimum and maximum length

Tags: regex

The following regex working as expected other than the case that it's not allowed that all characters are the same characters.

```
^(?=[A-Z0-9]+[ -]?[A-Z0-9]+)(?!([A-Z0-9])(?:\1|[ -]){5,10}).{5,10}$
```

here minimum is 5 characters and the maximum is 10 characters

```bash
11114 allowed its minimum length matched as 5 and one charcter is diff so not all same charcters
11111115 allowed as one charcter is different and its more than 5 charcter.
2222222  not allowed as all are same characters
222-22   not allowed as all are same charcters 
111-3 allowed as length 5 and one character is different 
444-45 allowed as length more than 5
1234565436 allowed as length with in range 5 to 10
```

Comment: You jut forgot a `$` in `(?!([A-Z0-9])(?:\1|[ -]){5,10})`. It should be `(?!([A-Z0-9])(?:\1|[ -]){5,10}$)`. See https://regex101.com/r/fmWKGQ/1

Comment: Thanks @Wiltor, working in all cases other than the below case 222-2 is accepted but its not valid as all are same characters even length match to 5.

Comment: @HarinathaReddy: `222-2` won't be validated in my suggested regex

Comment: Yes @anubhava, it's working as expected from your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to repeat range quantifier `{5,10}` multiple times as that makes changing this regex harder for other cases.

You may use this regex for this:

```bash
^(?=.{5,10}$)([A-Z0-9])(?!(?:[ -]?\1)+$)[A-Z0-9]*[ -]?[A-Z0-9]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/luYZty/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=.{5,10}$)`: Assert that we have 5 to 10 chars till end
- `([A-Z0-9])`: Match a letter or digit and capture in group #1
- `(?!(?:[ -]?\1)+$)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if same captured value is repeated till end
- `[A-Z0-9]*`: Match 0 or more letter or digit
- `[ -]?`: Match *optional* space or hyphen
- `[A-Z0-9]+`: Match 1 or more letter or digit
- `$`: End

Comment: Thanks @anubhava , its working as expected but other than this have another requirement as below 
to validate the text using the regex which allows one space or hyphen start with 97.  
```
regex: ^97(?=[0-9]+[ -]?[0-9]+)(?!([0-9])(?:\1|[ -]){2}).{3}$ 

ex: 97123 valid
    97-12 valid but not working as per the above reg 
    971-2 valid  
    9712- not valid

Comment: But that looks like a totally different problem from the one that you've asked here. As per norms on this forum please don't ask new questions from comments. Once your current problem is solved, you can post a new question and we'll try to help you.

Comment: @anubhava that happened to me on the last question from this poster...

Comment: @Nick: I wasn't aware. We should tell posters to not to use comment section for posting new unrelated questions.

Comment: Yes @anubhava, I am going to create a new post for the other problem, Sorry I was not aware to not ask questions in a comment, I thought it be a similar problem so instead of a new post tried to ask in a comment.